# using find with regex to execute a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find

I'm attempting to find all files with pattern `q[0-9]+[0-9]+[a-z]+.JPG` and for every file found execute `convert` (imagemagick) on each file found with output of `fooq[0-9]+[0-9]+[a-z]+.pdf`

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
find . -type f -regex './q[0-9]+[0-9]+[a-z]+.JPG' -exec bash -c 'for j; do convert "$j" q$((i++)).pdf; done' "$targetfile" {} +
```

The files aren't being found, and even when I change the command to:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
find . -type f -regex './q[0-9a-z]*.JPG' -exec bash -c 'for j; do convert "$j" q$((i++)).pdf; done' "$targetfile" {} +
```

to test the `find` command (which works in this case) the files aren't converted in the correct order. It looks like I need to insert a `sort` somewhere but I'm not sure how to do that. The filenames look like:

```
q1a.JPG
q7b.JPG
q11g.JPG
```

and the output filenames should look like:

```
fooq1a.pdf
fooq7b.pdf
fooq11g.pdf
```

How would I

1. create the proper regex
2. add `sort` to my script

If you have a better solution than mine, feel free to share. Cheers!

Comment: `shopt -s globstar; for i in **/q[0-9]*JPG; do echo $i; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `regex` used by `find` by default is basically *EMACS* regex. You can adjust the type of regex with the `-regextype <type>` option to `find` if needed. However, in your case with the filenames given, you can use a simple pattern match using the default regex as long as your filenames are relatively consistent. To handle the filenames in you example, you could do something like the following:

```
while read -r name; do 
    fname=$(basename "$name")
    convert "$name" "$(dirname "$name")/foo${fname/JPG/pdf}"
done < <(find ./ -type f -name 'q[0-9]*JPG')
```

(this presumes that `JPG` is the *extension* and you do not have `JPG` occurring again as part of the filename)

For example, to output what is taking place, you can simply substitute an `echo` or `printf` in place of `convert` for testing. A short example is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r name; do 
    fname=$(basename "$name")
    printf "convert %s %s\n" "$name" "$(dirname "$name")/foo${fname/JPG/pdf}"
done < <(find ./ -type f -name 'q[0-9]*JPG')
```

**Output**

```
$ bash cvttopdf.sh
convert ./q11g.JPG ./fooq11g.pdf
convert ./q1a.JPG ./fooq1a.pdf
convert ./q7b.JPG ./fooq7b.pdf
```

To `sort`, you would have no need to `sort` as part of the conversion. To view the files in sorted order, you can simply view in sorted order, both before or after with the normal tools of either `ls` or a more elaborate `sort` call. If you have some other need for sorting as part of the conversion, drop and note and I'll try and help further, I'm just somewhat confused as what purpose it would server in converting the jpeg to pdf?

Comment: Awesome! This is a ton more elegant than my possible solution would've been. Thanks